# Excel VBA Worksheet_Calculate event fires for different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Additional information (should make sense after reading the rest): If I open Workbook1.xlsm, then create a new workbook (Book1), I can enter data *and formulas, even volatile functions like `NOW(),`* in Book1!Sheet1 without triggering an instance-wide recalculation. I know this because I'm watching the calculate event handler in Workbook1!SheetX.

Tentative conclusion: Excel does *not* always automatically recalculate all formulas in all open workbooks. Rather, it only recalculates the active sheet (or maybe the active workbook) until something happens.

In this case, "something" is actually hiding the rows in the calculate event handler. I eliminated various lines of code and found that if I remove the `Me.Rows(x).Hidden = True` lines, the instance-wide recalculation doesn't happen. Applying a filter is an easy way to trigger the event, but adding a formula will produce the same result without using the filter, so it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the filters.

Anyway, hiding the rows somehow creates a condition that causes everything to recalculate. *Only after the macro hides the rows in SheetX* is the calculate macro in SheetX executed, and after that, it executes no matter which workbook or worksheet I enter data in. If I then open a third workbook through Windows Explorer, any changes there immediately fire the calculate macro. I can add an event handler in Sheet1 and verify that both handlers (SheetX and Sheet1) are executing, and SheetX executes *first* every time, even though the change was in Sheet1.

---

Caveat: Please don't get distracted by easier or better ways to hide rows or cells. I'm sure there are. My question has to do with what seems like a bug in Excel, so please focus on the firing of events *unless* the problem is related to the way the macro is written.

Situation:

Using Excel 2013 under Win7.

Workbook1, SheetX has VBA macro Worksheet_Calculate(). SheetX has data filtering on.

Open Workbook1.

Open a new workbook using File | New | Blank workbook. Its name is Book2.

Go back to Workbook1 and filter a column in SheetX (say, display only values of 3 in column A). [You could instead enter another formula anywhere in the range A4:C7.]

Enter a value into a cell in Book2.

Workbook1's Worksheet_Calculate() event fires. This can be demonstrated by setting a breakpoint.

Also, after the event fires, the TAB key no longer works in Book2 but works fine in Workbook1. This seems to be specific to the sheet being displayed, because if you create a Sheet2 in Book2, the TAB key will work until you enter something in Sheet2, after which it will work in Sheet1 until you enter something there. And vice versa ad nauseam.

SheetX contains the following. The macro's sole purpose is to hide rows 2 and 3, which in real life contain parameters that the user doesn't need to know about. When a filter is used, the rows otherwise become unhidden/visible. The formula in A3 is needed to be sure the Worksheet_Calculate event fires whenever anything in the worksheet changes.

```
    A      B      C 
1  data1 data2 data3    
2   
3  =A2      
4  3     A3     C5  
5  4     a3     C6  
6  3     A5     C7  
7  6     a6     C8
```

The macro is here:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    'Hide rows 2 & 3, which are the rows containing parameters.
    'This is necessary because whenever an autofilter selection is removed,
    ' Excel redisplays hidden rows and rows with 0 height.

    On Error GoTo errHdlr

    'First ensure that the event does not loop.
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Have to unprotect and re-protect the sheet to make these changes.
    Me.Unprotect

    Me.Rows(2).Hidden = True
    Me.Rows(3).Hidden = True

    'Have to specify that the user can insert hyperlinks
    ' and use filters.
    Me.Protect , , , , , , , , , , True, , , , True

    'Now restore event handling.
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Exit Sub

errHdlr:
    MsgBox "Error #" & Err.Number & ":" _
        & vbCrLf & "  " & Err.Description _
        & vbCrLf & "Please inform tech support.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
        "Worksheet_Calculate"

    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Because I was a little leery of the "Me" object, I checked with the debugger, and when I was in Book2, this is what I found when the event fired:

> ?me.Name
>
> SheetX
>
> ?me.Parent.name
>
> Workbook1.xlsm
>
> ?activesheet.name
>
> Sheet1
>
> ?activesheet.parent.name
>
> Book2

So clearly the "Me" object refers to SheetX in Workbook1, even though the active sheet is Sheet1 in Book2.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: You have a volatile function in Workbook1, SheetX. Might be TODAY(), INDIRECT(), OFFSET or some such.

Comment: @Jeeped - The only formula is =A2. There are no worksheet functions of any kind. Also, SheetX is the only worksheet in Workbook1. Why would it matter, though, if the activity going on is in *another workbook*?

Comment: Because a volatile function recalculates whenever **anything** in the workbook or **any workbook** in the same application instance changes.

Comment: `calculate()` is an APPLICATION level method. When it fires the application will perform the calculation on all workbooks in its workbooks collection. You can have two seperate instances of the Excel application open though and then possibly you won't be crossing streams when relying on the application.calculate() method and it's associated events.

Comment: Also the method you are using for hiding or showing cells is fine ;P and the context of `me` here will be the object in which the code resides, which will be `Sheet1` which you've discovered already.

Comment: @JNevill - So, if I understand this correctly, *any* formula implicitly uses the `calculate()` method, and so that causes *all* worksheets in all open workbooks to recalculate, which then fires the `worksheet.calculate` event *in every worksheet*, which would execute *all* 'worksheet_calculate' macros, regardless of which sheet started it all. But that leaves me with a couple of questions: (1) Book2!Sheet1 doesn't have *any* formulas, so why is the `worksheet calculate` event occurring every time I enter a value? (2) Why does it disable the TAB key?

Comment: @JNevill and @Jeeped - Looking at the MSDN entry on Excel recalculation: "When calculation is set to automatic, recalculation occurs after every data input and after certain events ...." This follows a long discussion of dependency trees, calculation chains, and dirty cells. One might think that Excel would only recalculate what it has to--i.e., only cells affected by whatever change you just made. But it kind of looks like any change in any sheet triggers recalculation across all open workbooks (but the article doesn't *say* it's related to the `calculate` method). How does this make sense?

Comment: @JNevill and Jeeped - Please see additional information I added to the top of the question.

Comment: YEp. This all sounds like routine calculate stuff. It's ugly and excel apparently makes an attempt at only firing what it needs to but gives up when things get to complicated and just fires everything, which seems reasonable. I'm curious if you can catch the `application.caller` in your event code and see what is spitting out. I've never done that for the `worksheet_calculate` event, so I'm not certain what would get loaded there. If it spits out something useful then you might be able to trap the caller in an `if` statement and only execute downstream code when necessary.

Comment: @JNevill - In the Immediate window, Typename(Application.Caller) shows "Error" and Application.Caller gives Error 2023. If I use it in the macro (Debug.Print), it raises Run-time error 13: Type mismatch.

Comment: Well... so much for that. Looks like you are at Excel's mercy on this one then. Perhaps hit up a different event like `worksheet_change()` which will have a caller AND a target you can query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`application.caller` event wouldn't help here, the only work around would be to have some specific text line "My Report123" in any cell, for example Cell #A1.

When you call `Worksheet_Calculate()` event the first line should be the checkpoint.

```
if activesheet.range("A1")<>"My Report123" then exit sub
```

This would solve the issue of the excel bug.

Comment: I am convinced that this is a bug in Excel, and I don't like bugs, which is why I spent so much time beating on this one. It really didn't have a major impact on my application, but I like your proposal for short circuiting the execution of the spurious event handler calls. However, you don't need to check for specific text. You can use this kind of logic: `If Me.Name <> Application.ActiveSheet.Name        Or Me.Parent.Name <> Application.ActiveSheet.Parent.Name Then Exit Sub`

Comment: I've found that this only partially works as now the event is triggered continually by the save event and will keep on looping.

Answer (score 0):

Rence's solution only partially works.

I agree that this is a bug in excel.

Once this starts happening in a workbook the event is triggered continually by the save event and will keep on looping. Strangely I have had this code running since 2010 or so and only now is this particular bug happening from a particular type of worksheet. Also it is common to use Worksheet_Calculate on a cell on a hidden worksheet (triggered by a filter etc) so it won't be the activesheet.range.
The following is what I have used to stop the Calculate event before it runs when a new workbook is opened or during a save event.
It does still seem to loop a few times but eventually stops:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
'18JAN2024- This code is to stop the calculate_stats function from running if 
'this event is triggered by another workbook opening, or a save event
If Me.Parent.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then Exit Sub

'This is to check that we aren't caught in a save operation
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo Exit_DoesntExist:
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tracking Graph").Select

  CalculateStats ‘the function that runs on the ‘Tracking Graph’ worksheet
  
Exit_DoesntExist:

End Sub
```