# Open Second Workbook Triggers VBA Code in First Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I open an Excel workbook which has some VBA code in it including Event code on one of the worksheets. I open a second workbook which has no VBA code in it at all but as soon as the second workbook opens, it triggers the VBA code to run in the first workbook. The code fails because the first workbook is not the Active Workbook. Anybody got any ideas why opening a second workbook should trigger event code in the first workbook?

Comment: To clarify, the VBA code which is triggered is the Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() code on the first workbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can replicate that -seems like opening a workbook triggers the calculate event in other open workbooks. Having said that, your event-handling code should not rely on any particular workbook being active when it runs, so it would help to post that if you want suggestions for fixes.

For example the worksheet object which corresponds to the sheet module can be referenced via `Me`, and the workbook containing that sheet is `Me.Parent`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Debug.print "calculating " & Me.Name & " in " Me.Parent.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I'm fairly new to VBA and I was a bit surprised that the code was triggered at all. Now that I know, I'll be wary of it. I can easily fix my code to stop the current trouble. It's fairly trivial.

Comment: And thanks for the pointer to Me keyword. I wasn't aware of it and I can see how useful it is.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in excel. I've posted a tentative solution here: [Excel VBA Worksheet_Calculate event fires for different workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004248/excel-vba-worksheet-calculate-event-fires-for-different-workbook/77836670#77836670)